# Subscribe to voluminous object in angular

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I've been straggling with the fetch of an object through a get request.

I have the following function in component.ts

```
private _getPolygonById(id: number) {
    let poly: any;
    this.dataService.getCollectionbyId(id).subscribe(data => {
        const res = data.json();
        poly = JSON.parse(res.string);
    });
    return poly;
}
```

my service.ts contains the following:

```
getCollectionbyId(id: number) {
    console.log("launching request");
    return this.http.get('api/project-collections/'+id);
}
```

The problem is that the poly is undefined and returned as so, the response is treated asynchronesly. how can I wait for the request untill it gets the response and then affect it to poly, to return it ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware the `_getPolygonById` function returns before you get a change to get the result in the subscribe block. Order of operations is as follows:

```
private _getPolygonById(id: number) {
    let poly: any; // 1
    this.dataService.getCollectionbyId(id).subscribe(data => {
        // 3
        const res = data.json();
        poly = JSON.parse(res.string);
    });
    return poly; // 2
}
```

You should return the observable from the `_getPolygonbyId` function and subscribe to the result when you want to consume it.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._getPolygonById(5).subscribe(// do something with the returned polygon)
}

private _getPolygonById(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.dataService.getCollectionbyId(id);
}
```

Comment: the getPolygonById is called through a click event, so I don't pre know the id that will be called. and data fetched is voluminous.